# Node js child process windows

Tags: node.js, exec, child-process

I am trying to open files using node js child processes.

I am using execFile command for that.

my code is as follows:

```
execFile("C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Media Player/wmplayer.exe",["a.mp4"] ,(err, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(stdout, stderr, err)
}).unref()
```

However in cmd just `a.mp4` command works.

I tried the following:

```
execFile("",["a.mp4"] ,(err, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(stdout, stderr, err)
}).unref()
```

or

```
execFile("a.mp4",(err, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(stdout, stderr, err)
}).unref()
```

and both do not work.

Is there a way i could run `a.mp4` without providing the application path to run the binary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can actually be done using exec.

execFile expects an executable (.exe) the first argument.

Where as exec blindly executes the command.

```
exec('"a.mp4"', (stdout, stderr, err)=>{
    console.log(stdout, stderr, err)
}
```

This will work fine.